# Cannot read property 'ident' of undefined when other objects work

Tags: javascript, html

I am extremely confused with this. I am trying to use an array to display some information in a table, but I can't get it to work on one object in an array. All of the other objects function perfectly fine, but this one returned undefined. I checked my PHP and it is returning just fine. Here is the code:

```
for (i=0;i<150;i++)
{
    var ident = arr[i]['ident'];
    $("#"+ident).click(function() {
        window.location.href = '?page=confirm&id='+ident;
    });

    document.getElementById("schedules").innerHTML+="<tr id='"+ident+"'><td>"+arr[i]['flight']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['departure']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['arrival']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['duration']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['aircraft']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['cat']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['operation']+"</td><td>"+arr[i]['carrier']+"</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Print the `arr[i]` to the console at the beginning of the loop. One of the indices is likely null.

Comment: Use the debugger in your browser.  Place a breakpoint on the line where you define `ident` and examine the contents of `arr`, potentially examining each element therein until you find the one that has no `ident` property.

Comment: @Danny It says the value of ident just fine when I do `console.log(arr[i])` and when I try `console.log(arr[i]['ident'])`.

Comment: @ChrisRockGM are you entirely positive that there are 150 objects in `arr`??? Why 150 and why not `arr.length`?

Comment: @Danny I fixed the problem. Turns out it was adding another element to the array that was undefined for some reason. However, my jQuery function doesn't work because whenever I click a table element nothing happens.

Comment: @ChrisRockGM Try. `$(document).on('click','#'+ident, function() { ... });`